# How to run AJAX in a loop synchronously(block before next iteration)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I want to run AJAX in a loop as below, but make sure that the ajax call finishes before progressing to the next loop iteration.

```
for (var i = 1; i < songs.length; i++) {
  getJson('get_song/' + i).done(function(e) {
    var song = JSON.parse(e);
    addSongToPlaylist(song);
  });
}
```

I know how to accomplish this with countdownlatches or event listeners in java, but have no idea how to do this in javascript.

Because I have of other AJAX calls going on at the same time, I can't use the `async=false`  parameter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not going to happen with an asynchronous call. Make the next request when the first comes back.

Comment: @Beginner Promises are great but they're not universally supported - jQuery uses deffered objects which aren't fully featured promises

Comment: Search "sequentially", not "synchronously".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it this way.

```
(function loop(i) {
  if(i < songs.length) getJson('get_song/' + i).done(function(e) {
    var song = JSON.parse(e);
    addSongToPlaylist(song);
    loop(i + 1);
  });
})(1);
```

Alternatively you can also use Async.js
https://github.com/caolan/async

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. This did it. The only thing I'd change in your answer is change the last (1) parenthesis to (0).